# Save Input fields as array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, html

I have Input fields that result in an array after POST:

```
<tr>
<td><input name="time['day'][]" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="time['from][]" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="time['to][]" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="time['day'][]" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="time['from][]" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="time['to][]" value="2"></td>
</tr>
```

This will be return:

> Array (
>
> ```
> ['day'] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 1
>         [1] => 2
>     )
>
> ['from] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 1
>         [1] => 2
>     )
>
> ['to] => Array
>     (
>         [0] => 1
>         [1] => 2
>     )
> ```
>
> )

But I would like to have this:

> Array (
>       [1] => Array
>
> ```
>     (
>         ['day'] => 1
>         ['from] => 1
>         ['to] => 1
>     )
>
> [2] => Array
>     (
>         ['day'] => 2
>         ['from] => 2
>         ['to] => 2
>     )
> ```
>
> )

I get this if I use:

```
<tr>
<td><input name="time[1]['day']" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="time[1]['from]" value="1"></td>
<td><input name="time[1]['to]" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input name="time[2]['day']" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="time[2]['from]" value="2"></td>
<td><input name="time[2]['to]" value="2"></td>
</tr>
```

But here comes the problem. I want to add new rows dynamicly (with JS) and would need to add always +1 to the first index.

How could I achive the second result without having to set the first index manually?

Comment: Start with 0 and check what you have before incrementing.

Comment: Arrays are zero-indexed, you know.

Comment: "I want to add new rows dynamicly (with JS) and would need to add always +1 to the first index" - What's the problem in this? Maybe I'm just not getting it.

Comment: BTW you don't need the quotes, e.g. you can just do this: `name="time[1][day]"`.

Comment: Two options: 1) Set the max value as a Javascript variable via PHP (messy) or 2) Fetch the value to use and increment it as needed. Here is a jQuery example. Adjust the selector as needed to match your markup: `$('input').attr('name').match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1]`;

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your html like this -

```
<tr>
    <td><input name="time['day'][]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input name="time['from'][]" value="1"></td>
    <td><input name="time['to'][]" value="1"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input name="time['day'][]" value="2"></td>
    <td><input name="time['from'][]" value="2"></td>
    <td><input name="time['to'][]" value="2"></td>
</tr>
```

After you get the values on server, lets say in GET array -

```
<?php 
    $myfinalarray = array();
    foreach ($_GET['time'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            $myfinalarray[$k][$key] = $v;
        }
    }
    print_r($myfinalarray);
?>
```

Output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['day'] => 1
            ['from'] => 1
            ['to'] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['day'] => 2
            ['from'] => 2
            ['to'] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using script to write script is better than to write each.  Just a concept to go with, you can use jquery to write into div for better result.

```
<script>
function callInput( i ) {
  document.write( "<tr><td><input name='time[" + i + "][day]' value='" + i + "'></td><td><input name='time[" + i + "][from]' value='" + i + "'></td><td><input name='time[" + i + "][to]' value='" + i + "'></td></tr>" );
}

function callRow( i ) {
  document.write( "<table>" );
  for( a = 0; a < i; a++ ) {
    callInput( a );
  }
  document.write( "</table>" );
}
</script>

<body onload="callRow( 4 )">
```